# required a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.SpringClientFactory' that could not be found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-ribbon

I have this test project which I would like to migrate to more recent version:

```
@Configuration
public class LoadbalancerConfig extends RibbonLoadBalancerClient  {

  public LoadbalancerConfig(SpringClientFactory clientFactory) {
    super(clientFactory);
  }

}
```

Full code example: https://github.com/rcbandit111/Generic_SO_POC/blob/master/src/main/java/org/merchant/database/service/sql/LoadbalancerConfig.java

Do you know how I can migrate this code to latest load balancer version?

Comment: have a look at this article https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-load-balancer. May be it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think examining the `RibbonAutoConfiguration` class gives you a good hint of how you should configure things.
First remove `@Configuration` from `LoadbalancerConfig`, I also renamed `LoadbalancerConfig` to `CustomLoadbalancer` to prevent confusion.

```
public class CustomLoadbalancer  extends RibbonLoadBalancerClient {
  public CustomLoadbalancer(SpringClientFactory clientFactory) {
    super(clientFactory);
  }
}
```

add the following dependency to your gradle
`com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon:2.7.18`

then add a configuration class like:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass({Ribbon.class})
@AutoConfigureAfter(name = "org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration")
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "spring.cloud.loadbalancer.ribbon.enabled",
    havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
@AutoConfigureBefore(LoadBalancerAutoConfiguration.class)
public class LoadBalancerClientConfig {
  @Autowired(required = false)
  private List<RibbonClientSpecification> configurations = new ArrayList<>();

  @Bean
  public CustomLoadbalancer customLoadbalancer() {
    return new CustomLoadbalancer(springClientFactory());
  }

  @Bean
  public SpringClientFactory springClientFactory() {
    SpringClientFactory factory = new SpringClientFactory();
    factory.setConfigurations(this.configurations);
    return factory;
  }

}
```

---

If you want to use Spring cloud load balancer instead of above configuration add `spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer` dependency to your `gradle.build` and for configuration you only need this bean:

```
  @LoadBalanced
  @Bean
  RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
  }
```

This `RestTemplate` pretty works identical to standard `RestTemplate` class, except instead of using physical location of the service, you need to build the URL using Eureka service ID.

Here is an example of how could you possibly use it in your code

```
 @Component
public class LoadBalancedTemplateClient {
  
  @Autowired
  RestTemplate restTemplate;
  @Autowired
  User user;

  public ResponseEntity<Result> getResult() {
    UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder
        .fromHttpUrl("http://application-id/v1/") // application id registered in eureka
        .queryParam("id", user.getUserId());
    return restTemplate.getForEntity(uriComponentsBuilder.toUriString(),
        Result.class);
  }
}
```

Also if you wish to use reactive client the process is the same first define the bean:

```
@LoadBalanced
@Bean
WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder() {
    return WebClient.builder();
}
```

and then inject and use it when you need:

```
  @Autowired
  private WebClient.Builder webClient;

  public Mono<String> doSomething() {
    return webClient
        .build()
        .get()
        .uri("http://application-id/v1/")
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(String.class);
  }
```

Also you can check documentation for additional information: [documentation](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-cloud-loadbalancer/)

Comment: As far as I know ribbon is deprecated. Do you know how I can use the latest version for `Load Balancer`?

Comment: @PeterPenzov yes it is deprecated. Do you mean Spring Cloud Load Balancer?

Comment: Yes, I would like to use it instead of Ribbon.

Comment: @PeterPenzov If I  correctly understood what is  your requirement, I updated the answer.

Comment: Can you extend the answer a little bit please? Looks like `User` is not needed? And `Result` is some kind of a custom object?

Comment: @PeterPenzov I think I did not convey my meaning correctly, I wanted to explain how to use `RestTemplate` in the form of a simple example.  `User` and `Result` are not needed, you can ignore them, just inject the `RestTemplate` bean and use according to your requirements.